# After installing ubuntu 12.04 my internet connection has completely disappeared

Tags: 12.04, wireless

On my PC after installing Ubuntu 12.04 my networks are completely gone. Inside the terminal, after typing in `nm-tool` I get the following:

```
The program nm-tool is currently not installed. You can install by typing:
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

After I type that in then my password I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  network manager : Depends: iputils-arping but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

I'm a complete novice when it comes to computers so I have no clue.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have network it stands to reason that your packages are broken and it is not able to install – Apt can't retrieve packages.

---

#### Manually download

As you are posting here you obviously have another unit with network access. If this one can be used to download packages you could do it manually.

- At [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) you can specify distribution and package; search; select hit-link; go to bottom of page; select package; select Architecture; copy mirror link / or direct link;

Download (this is for i386, precise):

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//pool/main/n/network-manager/network-manager_0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3_i386.deb
```

You'll also be served dependencies on that page.

- Or - in terminal if other machine is same version and architecture:

> ```
> uri=$(apt-cache show network-manager | grep "^Filename: " | cut -d' ' -f2) && wget "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/$uri"
> ```

To list dependencies and state do:

```
apt-rdepends network-manager --follow=DEPENDS --print-state
```

If `apt-rdepends` isn't installed it's dependencies should be installed

- Or - follow one of [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Installing_packages_without_an_Internet_connection).

---

#### Post some more information

Now. An easier way would perhaps be to try to fix the network using other tools.

#### A

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and issue the following commands:

```
lshw -C network
ifconfig -a
ip addr list
route -n
```

And post the output in your Question.

#### B

**Or, - more complete - run a script.** See code at bottom.

1. Save code to a file and copy it to machine without network.
2. Open terminal and make it executable:

   ```
   chmod 700 name_of_file
   ```
3. Run it and save output to file:

```
    ./name_of_file > result
    # or
    ./name_of_file | tee result
```

Sanitize it if you want and add it to your Question.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# No warranties, guaranties etc.
version=0.0.1

sep="=============================================================="

# has_tool "<tool>"
has_tool()
{
    command -v "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
}

# prnt_header "<tool>" "<arg-execute>"
prnt_header()
{
    printf ";; %s\n" "$sep"
    printf ";; = tool: %-52s =\n" "$1"
    [[ "$2" != "" ]] && printf ";; = arg : %-52s =\n" "$2"
    if ! has_tool "$1"; then
        e=";; = ERR: \`$1' not present."
        printf "%-63s =\n" "$e"
        printf ";; %s\n" "$sep"
        return 1
    fi
    if [[ "$1" =~ cat|more|less ]]; then
        if ! [[ -e "$2" ]]; then
            e=";; = ERR: File; \`$2' not present."
            printf "%-63s =\n" "$e"
            printf ";; %s\n" "$sep"
            return 1
        fi
    fi
    printf ";; %s\n" "$sep"
    
    return 0
}

# tool_info "<tool>" "<arg-version>" "<arg-execute>"
tool_info()
{
    local v=

    (($#!=3)) && {
        printf >&2 "* $0 ERR: Bad call to cmd_present. Missing arguments.\n"
        printf >&2 ";; '%s'\n" "$@"
        return 1
    }

    if ! prnt_header "$1" "$3"; then
        return 1
    fi
    if [[ $2 ]]; then
        printf ";; Version \$ %s %s\n" "$1" "$2"
        v=( $($1 $2 2>&1) )
        printf ";; %s\n" "${v[*]}"
    fi

    printf ";;\n"
}

# tool_do "<tool>" "<arg-version>" "<arg-execute>" "<sudo>"
tool_do()
{
    (($#!=4)) && {
        printf >&2 "* $0 ERR: Bad call to cmd_do. Missing arguments.\n"
        printf >&2 ";; '%s'\n" "$@"
        return 1
    }
    if ! tool_info "$1" "$2" "$3"; then
        return 1
    fi

    printf ";; Output:\n"
    
    (($4==1)) && sudo $1 $3 || $1 $3

    printf "\n;;\n"

    return 0
}

ping_gateways()
{
    if has_tool route; then
        # TODO: Check for UG flag
        gw=$(route -n | awk '{print $2}' | grep -o '^[0-9\.]*')
        for g in ${gw[*]}; do
            if ! [[ "$g" == "0.0.0.0" ]]; then
                tool_do "ping" "-V" "-c 3 $g" 0
            fi
        done
    fi
}

printf ";; _______________________ NET TEST _____________________________\n" | tee /dev/stderr
printf ";; v. %s\n\n" "$version" | tee /dev/stderr
printf >&2 ";; Working ...\n"

tool_info "NetworkManager" "--version" ""

printf >&2 ";; Hardware ...\n"
tool_do "lshw"  "-version"  "-C network" 1

#printf >&2 "\r\033[KVarious information ..."
printf >&2 ";; Various information ...\n"
tool_do "ifconfig" "-V" "-a" 0
tool_do "ip" "-V" "addr list" 0
tool_do "route" "-V" "-n" 0
tool_do "netstat" "-V" "-rn" 0
tool_do "iptables" "--version" "-n -L" 1


printf >&2 ";; Some cat'ing ...\n"
tool_do "cat" "" "/etc/network/interfaces" 0
tool_do "cat" "" "/etc/hosts" 0
tool_do "cat" "" "/etc/hosts.allow" 0
tool_do "cat" "" "/etc/hosts.deny" 0
tool_do "cat" "" "/etc/modules" 0
tool_do "cat" "" "/etc/modules.conf" 0
tool_do "cat" "" "/etc/resolv.conf" 0

printf >&2 ";; Some dig'ing ...\n"
tool_do "host" "" "localhost" 0
tool_do "nslookup" "" "localhost" 0
tool_do "nslookup" "" "askubuntu.com" 0
tool_do "dig" "" "." 0
tool_do "dig" "" "localhost" 0
tool_do "dig" "" "askubuntu.com" 0

printf >&2 ";; Ping gateways ...\n"
ping_gateways

printf >&2 ";; Ping various ...\n"
tool_do "ping" "" "-c 3 216.239.32.10" 0

printf >&2 ";; Ping google DNS ...\n"
# https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using
tool_do "ping" "" "-c 3 8.8.8.8" 0
tool_do "ping" "" "-c 3 8.8.4.4" 0

printf "\n;; Fine.\n" | tee /dev/stderr
```