# Can't connect to wifi and apt-get doesn't work

Tags: wireless, apt, broadcom

I've seen a ton of answers to fix my BroadCom BCM4312.

However, all of them require `apt-get` in the Terminal. For whatever reason, anything involving `apt-get` won't work. It just errors out with `Unable to locate package [package]`

Forgive me if this is an easy question; I just downloaded Ubuntu today.

**Edit:** I do have internet connection when using an Ethernet cord.

Comment: First check that you have type exact name of package and Your system should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no Internet connection, you can't install (as normal) by apt-get, as apt-get uses external servers etc.

Does this give you any help?: [After installing ubuntu 12.04 my internet connection has completely disappeared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229202/after-installing-ubuntu-12-04-my-internet-connection-has-completely-disappeared/229288#229288)

In short; you could try to follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Installing_packages_without_an_Internet_connection), or download by directly searching http://packages.ubuntu.com/, save to USB stick etc., and install on your machine without a network connection, using `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb` (or double-click it to pull up the Software Centre).

Comment: I do have an internet connection, using eithernet. I haven't checked the other things I can do yet (doing about 1000 other things atm) so I'm not sure if they work.

Comment: @chipperyman573: If you have internet using wire, use apt-get by that, then switch to wireless.